# How can I Hide Excel rows if SUM of contents = zero and skip rows containing any text?

Tags: text, excel, skip, vba

In line with a previous question I asked I am trying to hide rows that contain zeros, but skip over rows that contain any text in any one or more cells. I received excellent help previously skipping blank rows, and was hoping for more help now. I've searched through the internet on every forum I can find and have found nothing that does what I need it to. There are two codes on that hides and an exact copy of that one but with hide set to false. Here is the one that Hides.

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim R As Long
Dim Rng As Range
    If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        Set Rng = Selection
    Else
        Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If      
    For R = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    Set myRange = Range(Rng(R, 2), Rng(R, Rng.Columns.Count))
      If Application.CountBlank(myRange) <> myRange.Cells.Count And IsNumeric(myRange(Row)) = False Then
        If Application.Sum(myRange) = 0 Then
        Rng.Rows(R).Hidden = True
        End If
      End If
    Next R        
End Sub
```

By the way I know that the `IsNumeric(myRange(Row)) = False` really should probably be `= True`, but for some reason on one of my worksheets this setup works and if I change to True it pretty much does nothing.

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: You do not say what is wrong with this code. Does it hide rows it should not? Does it not hide rows it should? Why does `Set myRange ...` start at column 2?

Comment: Avoid range loops where you can, they are horrible wastes of code run time. Instead use a simple working column (manually or with VBA) and then `AutoFilter` it. But as per Tony's comment your exact issue could be clearer

Comment: I'm sorry, yes it hides rows with text in them that are headers for the respective section on the sheet. I've noticed that it takes time due to the loops but the areas these are applied aren't very large, and compared to the processing time of formulas in the sheets, this is nothing. Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your problems is `And IsNumeric(myRange(Row)) = False`

1. Row is undefined and never set.  So it will have the default value of `0`.  Therefore (since myRange is defined starting at column 2) `myRange(Row)` refers to the single cell in column `A` on the row `myRange` refers to.
2. If you drop the `(Row)` bit, `IsNumeric` will always return `FALSE`

Also, `Set myRange = Range(Rng(R, 2),` refers to Row R of the used range, offset one column to the right

Conclusion:

1. Assuming you want to test all cells, change to `Set myRange = Range(Rng(R, 1), Rng(R, Rng.Columns.Count))
2. To correctly test for no non-numeric cells use
    `If Application.Count(myRange) > 0 And _`
    `Application.CountBlank(myRange) + _`
    `Application.Count(myRange) = myRange.Cells.Count Then`

By the way, its good practice `DIM` all you variables.  This would have identified the issue with `(Row)`.  If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module this will become manditory.

Comment: This does excactly what I need. Thank you for your help and advice.

Answer (score 3):

When I tried your code, I got the following syntax errors:

- myRange is not defined.
- Row (as in myRange(Row)) is undefined.

Other issues with your code:

- myRange is a range so IsNumeric(myRange) will always be false.
- `If Application.CountBlank(myRange) <> myRange.Cells.Count` means blank rows are not hidden.

IsNumeric and IsNumber both operate on a single value.  I can find nothing in the documentation to suggest they can be made to operate on arrays, collections or ranges.  My experiments have produced results consistant with this.  I do not believe there is any way of handling the difficult cases except by checking individual cells within a row.

I think I have tested the following code for all the boundary conditions but I cannot guarantee this.  It hides blank rows and rows that contain nothing but zeros.  If a range is selected, columns outside that range are treated as blank.

```
Sub HideRows()

  Dim ColCrnt As Integer
  Dim Hide As Boolean
  Dim myRange As Range
  Dim R As Long
  Dim Rng As Range

  If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Set Rng = Selection
  Else
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  End If
  For R = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    Set myRange = Range(Rng(R, 1), Rng(R, Rng.Columns.Count))
    If Application.CountBlank(myRange) = myRange.Cells.Count Then
      ' Blank row
      Hide = True
    ElseIf Application.Sum(myRange) <> 0 Then
      ' At least on numeric cell with a non-zero value
      Hide = False
    Else
      ' Row contains one or more cells containing text, booleans or zeroes
      ' Hide if all these cells are zeros.
      ColCrnt = Rng.Columns.Count
      Set myRange = Rng(R, ColCrnt)
      If IsCellZero(myRange) Or IsEmpty(myRange) Then
        ' Last cell of row is zero or blank so will have to check row
        Do While True
          ' Skip to first non-blank cell to left or column 1
          ' if no non-blank cells
          Set myRange = myRange.End(xlToLeft)
          If myRange.Column < Rng(R, 1).Column Then
            ' Have move outside selection
            Hide = True
            Exit Do
          End If
          If myRange.Column = Rng(R, 1).Column Then
            ' Have reached column 1
            If IsCellZero(myRange) Or IsEmpty(myRange) Then
              ' Column 1 is zero or blank so nothing interesting on row
              Hide = True
              Exit Do
            Else
              ' Column 1 is not zero or blank
              Hide = False
              Exit Do
            End If
          End If
          If Not IsCellZero(myRange) Then
            Hide = False
            Exit Do
          End If
          If myRange.Column = Rng(R, 1).Column Then
            ' No non-zero cells found
            Hide = True
            Exit Do
          End If
        Loop
      Else
        ' Last cell of row is neither zero nor empty
        Hide = False
      End If
    End If
    If Hide Then
      Rng.Rows(R).Hidden = True
    Else
      Rng.Rows(R).Hidden = False
    End If
  Next R
End Sub
Function IsCellZero(Rng As Range) As Boolean

  ' Rng must be a single cell.  Returns true only if Rng.Value is numeric zero

  ' Function uses IsNumber because IsNumeric returns True
  ' for empty cells and booleans

  If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Rng.Value) Then
    If Val(Rng.Value) = 0 Then
      IsCellZero = True
    Else
      IsCellZero = False
    End If
  Else
    ' Value is blank, text or boolean
    IsCellZero = False
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and tips. I tried this out, and unfortunately it doesn't do exactly what I need. I should have been more specific about wanting to just hide rows with zeros, but skip over blank rows and rows with text. The reason that column A is not referenced is because it contains names corresponding to the numbers in subsequent columns (crosstab format). Thank you again. This was a big help in my understanding of VBA since I am very new to it.

Comment: I assume you can handle the minor changes necessary.  To ignore column 1, in `Set myRange ...` change the start column back to 2.  To accept blank rows.  delete `If Application.CountBlank ...`, the next two lines and the `Else` of the `ElseIf`.